# Delete `x,y,z` occurrence (or any permutation of it) from parent data set (dynamically)?

Tags: dynamic, data

Simple question:  I would like to dynamically specify a list of 3 elements, `{x,y,z}`.  Then I'd like to find that list, *or* any of its permutations, in a parent data set.  The parent data set is composed of lists which are at least 3 elements long (like mine), but could also be 4 or 5 elements long.  I will then be dynamically deleting the entire part which has an occurrence of `x,y,z` or `z,x,y` etc. from the parent data set (list of lists).

The first way I tried doesn't work for obvious reasons (I've removed `Dynamic` functionality because it doesn't work anyway):

```
data={{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,2,3},{3,2,1,9}};
x=3;
y=1;
z=2;
DeleteCases[data,Permutations[{x,y,z}]]
```

As you can see, I want this to find and delete the 3rd and 4th elements, so that `{{0,0,0},{1,1,1}}` is returned.  I'd also like to update `{x,y,z}` dynamically.

Are there any tricks to make this work?  Or am I doing it entirely wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way. It's not particularly fast, but may be fast enough for your purposes.

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 9}};
subseq = Sort@{3, 1, 2};
DeleteCases[data, {___, a_, b_, c_, ___} /; Sort[{a, b, c}] == subseq]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```